# why does gpg-agent create several sockets

Tags: gpg, gpg-agent

when using `gpg` with `gpg-agent`, following sockets are created in my `~/.gnupg` directory:

```
S.gpg-agent
S.gpg-agent.browser
S.gpg-agent.extra
S.gpg-agent.ssh
```

I assume, `S.gpg-agent` is the standard `gpg-agent` socket. But what are the others for?

I am not using gpg with ssh, or gpg with browser.

Where is it configured, that these are created automatically?

Can I disable them ?

I only need the standard `S.gpg-agent`

**I am using `gnupg  2.2.12` on Debian Buster.**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `gpg-agent` can have multiple personalities and deliver different services.

For example, you can stop having `ssh-agent` running on your box, and use `gpg-agent` as a drop in replacement... as long as you use the proper socket, `S.gpg-agent.ssh` because it has to implement the proper protocol `ssh` is expecting to discuss. Why could be that useful? For example, until very recently, `ssh` was not able to use keys stored in FIDO2/U2F (like Yubikeys), this was only added in 8.2 released not long ago, which then makes things dead simple as explained in https://blog.snapdragon.cc/2020/02/23/direct-fido2-u2f-support-in-openssh-8-2-on-macos/

Before that, `gpg-agent` would be used, because `gpg` has support for the U2F thing as handled like a smartcard. This is one of the canonical documentation on how to do that: https://florin.myip.org/blog/easy-multifactor-authentication-ssh-using-yubikey-neo-tokens

Now back to `gpg-agent`, its full manual is at https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Invoking-GPG_002dAGENT.html#Invoking-GPG_002dAGENT

You can find all options at https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Agent-Options.html#Agent-Options which can be put in a configuration file, typically `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`

We can learn for example:

1. about the `.extra` one, we can learn both how to disable it and what it is used for:

> ```
> --extra-socket name
> ```
>
> The extra socket is created by default, you may use this option to change the name of the socket. To disable the creation of the socket use “none” or “/dev/null” for name.
>
> Also listen on native gpg-agent connections on the given socket. The intended use for this extra socket is to setup a Unix domain socket forwarding from a remote machine to this socket on the local machine. A gpg running on the remote machine may then connect to the local gpg-agent and use its private keys. This enables decrypting or signing data on a remote machine without exposing the private keys to the remote machine.

2. For ssh support, the `.ssh` one:

> `--enable-ssh-support`
>
> `--enable-putty-support`
>
> The OpenSSH Agent protocol is always enabled, but gpg-agent will only set the SSH_AUTH_SOCK variable if this flag is given.
>
> In this mode of operation, the agent does not only implement the gpg-agent protocol, but also the agent protocol used by OpenSSH (through a separate socket). Consequently, it should be possible to use the gpg-agent as a drop-in replacement for the well known ssh-agent.

3. For the browser socket and more information you can use https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GnuPG#gpg-agent that says:

> `gpg-agent` is mostly used as daemon to request and cache the password for the keychain. This is useful if GnuPG is used from an external program like a mail client. gnupg comes with systemd user sockets which are enabled by default. These sockets are `gpg-agent.socket`, `gpg-agent-extra.socket`, `gpg-agent-browser.socket`, `gpg-agent-ssh.socket` and `dirmngr.socket`.

> The main `gpg-agent.socket` is used by gpg to connect to the `gpg-agent` daemon.
>
> The intended use for the `gpg-agent-extra.socket` on a local system is to set up a Unix domain socket forwarding from a remote system. This enables to use gpg on the remote system without exposing the private keys to the remote system. See gpg-agent(1) for details.
>
> The `gpg-agent-browser.socket` allows web browsers to access the gpg-agent daemon.
>
> The `gpg-agent-ssh.socket` can be used by SSH to cache SSH keys added by the ssh-add program. See #SSH agent for the necessary configuration.
>
> The `dirmngr.socket` starts a GnuPG daemon handling connections to keyservers.

So there is no harm in having them even if you don't use them.
If you really want to make sure they are not there, you can try to put the following in a gpg-agent configuration file:

```
extra-socket /dev/null
browser-socket /dev/null
```

I did not test that, the documentation does not speak about `browser-socket` but this older question does: https://askubuntu.com/questions/777900/how-to-configure-gnupgs-s-gpg-agent-socket-location

Comment: thank you for the great answer. I disabled browser and extra by adding `extra-socket /dev/null` and `browser-socket /dev/null` to my config. But how do I disable the ssh socket `S.gpg-agent.ssh` ?

Comment: @400theCat This answer indirectly says it: it should be possible to prevent socket creation by masking the corresponding systemd unit, e.g. `systemctl --user mask gpg-agent-ssh.socket` (the socket will be gone after a reboot). However, I don't think this will make much difference neither in terms of security nor in terms of system resources; you may want to explain the reason you're trying to do that in more detail, users here may be able to give you more effective advice.

Comment: @fra-san - I am not using systemd. I am starting gpg-agent manually. is there a way to configure this using the config file ?

Comment: @400theCat I don't think so. Looking at the [code](https://git.gnupg.org/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=gnupg.git;a=blob;f=agent/gpg-agent.c;h=ffd85d196c19719e5c05a50d77f4d430036dbc17;hb=7d8f4ee7cf56eda988acdc909160cbac71bff18a), the SSH socket seems to be created unconditionally (as opposed to the "browser" and "extra" sockets).